# Time complexity of creating a minimal spanning tree if the number of edges is known

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Suppose that the number of edges of a connected graph is known and the weight of each edge is distinct, would it possible to create a minimal spanning tree in linear time?

To do this we must look at each edge; and during this loop there can contain no searches otherwise it would result in at least n log n time. I'm not sure how to do this without searching in the loop. It would mean that, somehow we must only look at each edge once, and decide rather to include it or not based on some "static" previous values that does not involve a growing data structure.

So.. let's say we keep the endpoints of the node in question, then look at the next node, if the next node has the same vertices as prev, then compare the weight of prev and current node and keep the lower one. If the current node's endpoints are not equal to prev, then it is in a different component .. now I am stuck because we cannot create a hash or array to keep track of the component nodes that are already added while look through each edge in linear time.

Another approach I thought of is to find the edge with the minimal weight; since the edge weights are distinct this edge will be part of any MST. Then.. I am stuck. Since we cannot do this for n - 1 edges in linear time.

Any hints?

---

EDIT

What if we know the number of nodes, the number of edges and also that each edge weight is distinct? Say, for example, there are n nodes, n + 6 edges?

Then we would only have to find and remove the correct 7 edges correct?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to compute an MST faster by knowing how many edges there are in the graph and that they are distinct.  In the worst case, you would have to look at every edge in the graph before finding the minimum-cost edge (which must be in the MST), which takes Ω(m) time in the worst case.  Therefore, I'll claim that *any* MST algorithm must take Ω(m) time in the worst case.

However, if we're already doing Ω(m) work in the worst-case, we could do the following preprocessing step on any MST algorithm:

1. Scan over the edges and count up how many there are.
2. Add an epsilon value to each edge weight to ensure the edges are unique.

This can be done in time Ω(m) as well.  Consequently, if there were a way to speed up MST computation knowing the number of edges and that the edge costs are distinct, we would just do this preprocessing step on any current MST algorithm to try to get faster performance.  Since to the best of my knowledge no MST algorithm actually tries to do this for performance reasons, I would suspect that there isn't a (known) way to get a faster MST algorithm based on this extra knowledge.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your analysis is correct, but we also have a matching linear theoretical upper bound.  I'm a little perplexed by your comment about "no MST algorithm actually tries to do this for performance reasons," though --- do you actually know an application where MSTs are computed and people care deeply enough to do performance engineering of the MST code?

Answer (score 2):

There's a famous randomised linear-time algorithm for minimum spanning trees whose complexity is linear in the number of edges.  See "A randomized linear-time algorithm to find minimum spanning trees" by Karger, Klein, and Tarjan.

The key result in the paper is their "sampling lemma" -- that, if you independently randomly select a subset of the edges with probability p and find the minimum spanning tree of this subgraph, then there are only |V|/p edges that are better than the worst edge in the tree path connecting its ends.

As templatetypedef noted, you can't beat linear-time.  That all edge weights are distinct is a common assumption that simplifies analysis; if anything, it makes MST algorithms run a little slower.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a number of edges (N) is known does not influence the complexity in any way. N is still a finite but unbounded variable, and each graph will have different N. If you place a upper bound on N, say, 1 million, then the complexity is O(1 million log 1 million) = O(1).

The fact that each edge has distinct weight does not influence the program either, because it does not say anything about the graph's structure. Therefore knowledge about current case cannot influence further processing, as we cannot predict how the graph's structure will look like in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of edges is close to n, like in this case `n-6` (after edit), we know that we only need to remove 7 edges as every spanning tree has only `n-1` edges.
The [Cycle Property](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjwiqrrjt3dAhUl94MKHZAaARgQygQwAHoECAkQBg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMinimum_spanning_tree%23Cycle_property&usg=AOvVaw17vRp_qt_5wfg6wRVd_Q3t) shows that the most expensive edge in a cycle does not belong to any Minimum Spanning tree(assuming all edges are distinct) and thus, should be removed.

Now you can simply apply *BFS* or *DFS* to identify a cycle and remove the most expensive edge. So, overall, we need to run BFS 7 times. This takes `7*n` time and gives us a time complexity of `O(n)`. Again, this is only true if the number of edges is close to the number of nodes.